# Derivation Dirac equation

Tags: special-relativity, notation, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

In introduction to elementary particles by David Griffiths p.227, Griffiths says that

$$(\beta^kp_k + mc)(\gamma^{\lambda}p_{\lambda} -mc) = \beta^k\gamma^{\lambda}p_kp_{\lambda} - mc(\beta^k - \gamma^k)p_k - m^2c^2$$ while deriving the Dirac equation.

However, I don't understand how he gets the second term on the right hand side of the equation.
Why the indices of $\gamma$ and $p$ are now $k$ instead of $\lambda$?

Comment: Do you understand the Einstein summation convention? Do you understand the concept of a dummy index as opposed to a free index?

Comment: I still find the Einstein summation a bit tricky, but I never hear about dummy index.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation): ‘An index that is summed over is a summation index, in this case "i ". It is also called a dummy index since any symbol can replace "i " without changing the meaning of the expression (provided that it does not collide with other index symbols in the same term).’

Comment: In other words, $\gamma^{\lambda}p_{\lambda} = \gamma^kp_k$, because they both represent $\gamma^0p_0+\gamma^1p_1+\gamma^2p_2+\gamma^3p_3$. However, you need to have different index names in $\beta^k\gamma^{\lambda}p_kp_{\lambda}$ because this stands for $(\beta^0p_0+\beta^1p_1+\beta^2p_2+\beta^3p_3)(\gamma^0p_0+\gamma^1p_1+\gamma^2p_2+\gamma^3p_3)$ which is not the same as $(\beta^0p_0\gamma^0p_0+\beta^1p_1\gamma^1p_1+\beta^2p_2\gamma^2p_2+\beta^3p_3\gamma^3p_3)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the indices of $\gamma$ and $p$ are now $k$ instead of $\lambda$?

They are dummy indices, so it does not matter what they are called.

A "dummy index" is one that is summed over. This is different from a free index that can be treated like a variable.

Here's an example:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i b_i = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3 \tag{A}
$$
$$
\sum_{j=1}^3 a_j b_j = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3 \tag{B}
$$

As you can see, the right-hand side of Eq. (A) and the right-hand side of Eq. (B) are exactly the same, which means that it did not matter whether the summation variable was called $i$ or called $j$.

---

Here's an example using the Einstein summation convention:
$$
a_\mu b^\mu = a_0 b_0 - a_1 b_1 - a_2 b_2 - a_3 b_3 
$$
$$
a_\nu b^\nu = a_0 b_0 - a_1 b_1 - a_2 b_2 - a_3 b_3 
$$

Again, you see it does not matter whether I call the summed ("dummy") index $\mu$ or $\nu$, since it is summed over and both RHSs above are the manifestly the same.